# Восстановление данных без их потери

Tags: windows-10, файловая-система, hdd

После неудачной установки Ubuntu, слетела файловая система, не могу восстановить ценные данные.

Как из HDD сделать один диск не потеряв данные ?

[image: То что нужно восстановить]

[image: Возможные вариации с диском]

Comment: Воспользовался Hetman Partition Recovery. Вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользовался Hetman Partition Recovery - получилось.

Answer (score 1):

1. Стоит сначала сдалать копию раздела (или даже всего диска) на внешний диск - может пригодиться, если что-то вдруг пойдёт не так.
2. Раз есть раздел, можно попробовать кликнуть его правой кнопкой и назначить ему букву. Это вполне может помочь, если проблема была только отсутствии буквы (такое иногда случается с внешними дисками, если настроенная для них ранее буква оказалась занята). С другой стороны, назначение буквы сделает его доступным для программ, и в случае, если запустится что-то, что может писать на него данные (инсталляторы программ могут выбирать диск с самым большим объёмом свободного места для временных файлов, в планировщике может стоять дефрагментация и т. д.), это может навредить.
3. Если на прошлом шаге данные не появились, стоит воспользоваться программами для восстановления удалённых данных. Я бы воспользовался Recuva - у меня получалось ей восстанавливать файлы после форматирования.

Кстати, насколько я вижу, Recuva сейчас умеет работать с разделами без букв - так что можно её использовать вместо шага 2. Но при наличии бэкапа раздела, я бы сначала проверил - может самого 2 достаточно.